# how to write a query to set the value of a column based on another column

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-update, case

I have table its name is `FDWelcomeCall` and there are columns `wcstatus` and `datecompleted`.

I want to select `datecompleted`. But I want to set the value of `datecompleted` to `NULL` if the `wcstatus` value is `0` or `1`, other than that the value of `datecompleted` will be appeared normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` construct, like :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN wc_status IN (0, 1) THEN NULL ELSE datecompleted END datecompleted 
FROM FDWelcomeCall
```

If you are looking to actually set `datecompleted` to `NULL` when `wc_status` is `0` or `1` :

```
UPDATE FDWelcomeCall
SET datecompleted = NULL
WHERE wc_status IN (0, 1)
```